# Retrieve Unique Developer Key Programmatically?

Tags: android

I was wondering if it is possible to programmatically retrieve the unique developer key/credentials that is used to sign the app? Basically I'm looking to retrieve unique developer information at runtime that can verify their identity as the author of the app.

Also, does this require any permissions if the app is running on a users phone whilst retrieving said info?

Many thanks for your help

**EDIT:**
I think this might help me
http://developer.android.com/reference/javax/security/cert/Certificate.html

Comment: Do you want this to work on rooted devices, or can you assume a non-rooted device controlled by the Google or Amazon (or other) store?

Comment: I hadn't considered it really. Wouldn't the application have associated developer info packaged with it regardless? Or are you saying this could be tampered with on a rooted device?

Answer (score 0):

With a bit of research I found [this](http://thomascannon.net/misc/android_apk_certificate/) to get the certificate. If I then use [getPublicKey()](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/security/cert/Certificate.html#getPublicKey%28%29) to return the public key this will be sufficient given that I will know the public key of the developer who I am trying to verify with [verify (PublicKey key)](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/security/cert/Certificate.html#verify%28java.security.PublicKey%29).